# Submenu links doesnt work on multilevel jQuery menu

Tags: jquery, css, menu, submenu

im working on a very simple "Multilevel menu" with jQuery.

[Here is the code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLdOPj)

The links inside the `.sub-nav` can't be clicked because the parent `li` is above them. ¿Any help?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind click event to link inside `<li>` element, when clicked get parent of this link element and then slide toggle sub-nav.

Give it a try. ;)

EDIT:

I made it with a next() jQuery selector: here's js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav > li > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
});
```

Notice that `>` prevents the clicked `<li>` element itself from sliding. It basically says that I want to bind event of clicking link which is direct child of `<li>` element which is direct child of an element with `.nav` class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It works! :) The `>` solved my problem. Gracias amigo!

Comment: Always happy to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here your code. I added class link to a has content real link and wrote a function for them

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('.nav li:has(ul)').bind('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).children('ul').stop().slideToggle("fast");

 });

  $('li a.link').on('click', function(e){
    alert('clicked');
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
        <h1>Page title</h1>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="#">Obras</a>
            <ul class="sub-nav">
              <li><a class="link" href="http://www.google.com.ar">Series</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Series</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Series</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Series</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Series</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">CV</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
          <li><a href="#l">Misceláneas</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

More about [stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)